# Как уменьшить значки на рабочем столе в Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, desktop

Как можно изменить размер знаков на рабочем столе в Linux Mint 17.1 Mate?

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=159291

Answer (score 2):

1. Устанавливаешь dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

2. Запускаешь dconf-editor (можно из той же консоли, не помню, под каким именем он попадает в меню приложений)
3. В открывшемся окне поиском ищешь параметр `рdefault-zoom-level`

Вот здесь очень важно не ошибиться, нужна ветка mate - caja - icon-view

Ну и выбираешь подходящий размер из списка.